# ImageIO.write behavior is different depending on format types even though they are accepted writers

Tags: java, java-io, javax.imageio, image-conversion

so i am converting a tiff image using ImageIO and im observing odd behavior where the image converts fine for some types but not for others and its not always the case some image will convert the raw or bmp while others will not even though all images are from the same source.

```
byte[] imageByteArray = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(imgData);
BufferedImage decodedImg = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByteArray));
ImageIO.write(decodedImg, format, os);
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(os.toByteArray());
```

output for valid types: `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames()));`

`[JPEG 2000, JPG, jpg, JPEG2000, tiff, bmp, BMP, gif, GIF, WBMP, png, PNG, raw, RAW, JPEG, pnm, PNM, tif, TIF, TIFF, jpeg2000, wbmp, jpeg, jpeg 2000]`

Formats that work: `[jpg, JPG, JPEG, tiff, TIF, tif, TIFF, png, gif, GIF, jpeg]`

Formats that DONT work: `[JPEG2000, JPEG 2000, raw, RAW, pnm, PNM, jpeg2000, jpeg 200]`

Formats that "work" but return false: `[wbmp, WBMP, bmp, BMP]` For these im able to retrieve image data such as height from `decodedImg.getHeight()`

Comment: The JRE does not support all those formats. So I assume you are using an external plugin that provides readers/writers for all those formats. In fact all formats that are supported by the JRE [JPG, jpg, bmp, BMP, gif, GIF, WBMP, png, PNG, wbmp, jpeg, JPEG] are working just fine. Maybe it is a problem of the plugin you are using. Have you considered using JAI? Can you provide some context about this plugin?

Comment: It's hard to tell what is your problem here... It could be that you have installed JAI, but missing some dependencies? I also think you are confusing file formats and the image data they (can) store.. Ie. JPEG can store RGB or gray data, but has no standard way to store alpha, don't support palette or B/W images, while a format like GIF can only store palette images and WBMP can only store B/W. TIFF on the other hand, is the "swiss army knife" of image file formats, and can store pretty much anything (but there's probably no encoder/decoder that supports all the possibilities in the format)...